# Open source solution for enterprise configuration management with ui/dashboard

Tags: configuration, enterprise

Working on the enterprise application that has multiple components/services. Instead of storing configuration for each component/service per environment.

Looking for something which allow me to store configuration in hierarchy such as through interactive UI.

Application-1 -> Component-1 -> Env -> Resource-1 -> Option-1:Value-1 [leaf level]

Application-1 -> Component-1 -> Env-1 -> Resource-1 -> Option-1:Value-1 [leaf level]

Application-1 -> Component-2 -> Env -> Resource-1 -> Option-1:Value-1 [leaf level]

And get this values back through method such as rest service calls.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, you are looking for a configuration solution for a system that is comprised of multiple components/services.

In the company where I work we have developed a simple and powerful configuration platform designed to enable an entire system’s configuration from a single location, making the configuration process convenient, clear, safe, organized and informative.

Some of the key features we support include:

- A single convenient GUI
- Parameters meta-data
- Levels and Inheritance
- Component upgrades
- Meta-data Validation
- Third-party component support (we support everyone)
- Support and management of namespaces and versions
- Advanced features like auto-link

If we release this to open-source, would you be interested?

Comment: Looking for something you described in your answer. Good to consider such solution. Is there similar free source available in market ?

Comment: Zookeeper is the closest I know of, but it doesn't support hierarchy.

Comment: @neo Although not open source and not exactly what you're looking for, you might want to take a look at [ScriptRock](https://www.scriptrock.com/).

Comment: Yes! Please release it.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear, if you are looking for a coding foundation or a ready to go app.
It is unclear, what is your focus (REST, hierarchy, UI).
It is unclear, why you need the combination of REST, hierarchy, UI and where there is room for alternatives.

short answer brainstorming:

- flat ini file + notepad (-> no REST)
- mysql + mysql workbench  (-> no REST, no built-in hierarchy)
- http://sourceforge.net/directory/business-enterprise/enterprise/bsm/cmdb/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/ (-> ready to go tool)
- http://restsql.org/doc/Overview.html (framework to add hierarchy support on sql)

Answer (score 0):

You may have heard of WebMin and VirtualMin which are a CPanel-like UI for server management. A little-known feature of both is that they can be controlled from CLI and also remotely. Here is the [documentation on the "VirtualMin Remote API"](http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/developer/http) which allows you to control services and configuration via HTTP and get output via XML or JSON.

Now you still need to [create your own modules](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/WebHome#Developer_Docs) which may or may not be hard work but it's probably going to be much easier than writing the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm rather looking for solution which was described by summerbulb in his answer.